# Incorrect SUPEE-8167 patch name

Tags: patches, supee-8167

just to check if the download file is correct.
The name of the patch for CE 1.9.1.0 is:

`PATCH_SUPEE-8167_EE_1.14.1.0_1.14.3.2_v1-2017-05-08-02-42-22`

Is that correct? Because it seems that it is a patch for Enterprise Edition (EE).
Thanks in advance
francesco

Answer (score 1):

I noticed this as well. Looking at the contents of the patch file I also couldn't see the changes it makes present in the 1.9.3.3 source code which is supposed to include SUPEE-8167.

I have seen CE patches with an EE prefix applied to CE shops before and assumed they were just identical patches, but I am not sure in this case.

Comment: Uh, yeah, WTF? Is this legit?

Comment: @yldziner yes its legit, sometimes magento deploys EE patches for CE since to be patched code is the same.